# A problem regarding linking verbs

Tags: verbs

Taste, appear, look, seem are linking verbs and cannot be used in progressive tenses.

> The grapes are **tasting** sour.
>   She is **seeming** bad.
>  are wrong.

But we usually say

> You are **looking** handsome.
>   You are looking beautiful.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of ***looking handsome***, it is not the progressive aspect that you are using, but the **gerund**. It is a gerund phrase, being used attributively. You actually get the same with other linking verbs as well, either using the gerund phrase attributively or as a normal noun phrase, and they can be used in a number of ways:

> Tasting sour, the grapes were not popular.
>   Feeling unwell, he went back to bed.
>   I don't like feeling hungry.
>   Being red, the dress made her stand out.

I'd also take issue with the idea that we usually say *you are looking* for those examples; "you look handsome" is also perfectly normal. Which is more common probably depends on dialect.

It's also worth noting that, in some dialects, "are tasting sour" wouldn't be strange at all, so long as there were a more specific determiner than *the*:

> These grapes are tasting sour.

Or with some other specification that seems more precise and less general than the example you gave:

> The grapes are tasting sour today.

In some dialects, that would seem weird, utterly unnatural; in others it's perfectly normal. By similar token, in some dialects "you are looking handsome" would be weird, but "you are looking handsome today" would be fine.

Of course, when *to taste* is used in its active sense - such as *wine tasting* - it's normal to use the progressive, as it is with any other verb that is sometimes linking and sometimes not.

Comment: I can't say it looks much like a gerund usage to me (though I'd certainly buy it in contexts such as ***Looking good** is a side-effect of being fit*). I note the continuous has gained traction with [*You're looking **good***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You%27re+looking+good%2CYou+look+good&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CYou%20%27re%20looking%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CYou%20look%20good%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CYou%20're%20looking%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CYou%20look%20good%3B%2Cc0) in recent decades, but not with *...looking **tired***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are a lot of cases where it's easy enough to argue either way on gerunds versus participles. This is based on what I've learned, but people do teach it different ways. The cases where it's an attributive gerund phrase not linked with a verb are definitely gerunds by how I learned it - and where it's filling the same role with different structure would strike me as still being gerunds.

Comment: Well, you cite *Feeling unwell, he went back to bed* as a "gerund" usage, and obviously you think the same applies to *I'm feeling sick, You're looking good*, etc. But I'm not clear as to whether you're saying the "gerund" label is affected by the presence of an adverbial element in *You're looking good today, I'm working tomorrow,* etc. And what about, say, ***cycling**?* Obviously a gerund in *My hobbies are cycling and weightlifting*, but surely not in *I'm cycling to London tomorrow.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was limiting it to linking verbs, seeing as that's what the question is about... some authorities do say that linking verbs aren't used in progressive form (and some don't, and some say "some aren't").